# Scrolling over fixed fullscreen DIVs execute animated slides as seen on Bagigia.com

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

Is there some kind of plugin or framework I can use to copy the functionality found on http://bagigia.com? I know I can WGET the entire source but the demand is for something very custom and reverse engineering the several JS files found on Bagigia seems like a bad idea. Or is it? Is it my best option?