# how to make images swap as you scroll to appear in 3d

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I have a client who has several powerpoint slides that they want to animate through seamlessly as the user scrolls down the page vertically. It is similar to this page:

http://www.bagigia.com/

Any advice on how to accomplish this? If you're familiar with webflow - that's usually the program of choice I use to help create the clean code for fast deployment but even raw code is totally welcome, OF COURSE!

Essentially, they have a water bottle that they have taken photos of in different positions and as they scroll down the page they want the water bottle to turn on its side and then towards the viewer. They have all of these images photographed and isolated but I can't figure out how to code it so that the bottle appears to animate.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287412/scrolling-over-fixed-fullscreen-divs-execute-animated-slides-as-seen-on-bagigia-com (linking for reference)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the Bagigia source code it appears they have a bunch of ordered `div`s with background images inside a parent container `#rotation .container`. Each `div` has one angled product photo set as the `background-image`.

The jQuery code is bound to `scroll` events with `$window.bind('scroll', function(){/*code*/})` which updates the `.container`'s `left` property by a certain amount each time. This gives the impression of the images animating in rotation where really it is just sliding images to the left and off the visible area.

It is worth noting that the `div` elements have their `width` and `height` set on page load and on window `resize` event. This helps to determine what the `left` position should be updated by.

You can see all of this in their source code which is quite neatly formatted. Check out their script for the home page rotation at http://www.bagigia.com/js/bagigia.home.rotation.js?v=d38yhf5

Your question was only about the image rotation so I won't comment on the other features however you can always view the other source code as needed.

Good luck on building this yourself. I'd be interested in the results if you are able to share it, or perhaps write a blog post to share your approach, learnings, and outcomes.

Should Bagigia update/remove their website, I've pasted some of the relevant code below which is directly from their source and not my own work.

```
<div id="rotation">

  <div class="popup">
    <div class="item" id="popup-bag1"></div>
    <div class="item" id="popup-bag5"></div>
    <div class="item" id="popup-bag12"></div>
    <div class="item" id="popup-bag17"></div>
    <div class="item" id="popup-bag21"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="bag-angle show" id="bag0" rel="popup-bag1"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag1" rel="popup-bag1"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag2" rel="popup-bag1"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag3"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag4"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag5" rel="popup-bag5"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag6" rel="popup-bag5"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag7" rel="popup-bag5"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag8"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag9"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag10"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag11"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag12" rel="popup-bag12"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag13" rel="popup-bag12"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag14" rel="popup-bag12"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag15"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag16"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag17" rel="popup-bag17"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag18" rel="popup-bag17"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag19" rel="popup-bag17"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag20"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag21" rel="popup-bag21"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag22" rel="popup-bag21"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag23" rel="popup-bag21"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag24"></div>
    <div class="bag-angle" id="bag25"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $window = $(window);
  var $introBox = $('#intro');
  var $rotationBox = $('#rotation');
  var $containerBox = $('#rotation .container');
  var $bags = $('#rotation .bag-angle');
  var blankHeight = 200;
  var index = -1;

  var $blankOpen = $('<div class="bag-blank"></div>');
  $blankOpen.height($window.height() + blankHeight).appendTo($('#bag-blank-space'));

  $bags.each(function(index){
    var $blank = $('<div class="bag-blank" rel="bag' + index + '"></div>');
    $blank.height(blankHeight).appendTo($('#bag-blank-space'));
  });

  $('.bag-blank:last').height(blankHeight/2);

  $window.bind('scroll', function(){
    var opacity = ($window.scrollTop()) / (($window.height()));
    if (opacity <= 1){
      if ($window.scrollTop() <= $introBox.height()){
        $rotationBox.css({opacity: opacity});
      }
    }else{
      $rotationBox.css({opacity: 1});
    }

    $('#bag-blank-space .bag-blank').each(function(i){   
      if ($window.scrollTop() > $(this).position().top){
        index = i;
      }   
    });

    if (index < $bags.length){

      var $toShow =  $('#rotation .bag-angle:eq(' + index + ')');
      var $toHide = $('#rotation .bag-angle.show');

      if (!$toShow.hasClass('show')){
        $toShow.addClass('show');
        $toHide.removeClass('show');

        var $popup = $('.popup .item#' + $toShow.attr('rel'));

        if ($popup.length > 0 && !$rotationBox.is(':animated') && $rotationBox.position().top >= 0){
          if (!$popup.hasClass('show') && !$rotationBox.hasClass('hide')){
              $('.popup .item.show').removeClass('show').stop(false,true).animate({opacity:0},'fast');
              if ($rotationBox.position().top >= 0){
                $popup.addClass('show').stop(false,true).animate({opacity:1},'fast');
              }
          }
        }else{
          $('.popup .item.show').removeClass('show').stop(false,true).animate({opacity:0},'fast');
        }

        $containerBox.css({left: -1 * index * $window.width()});
      }

      if ($rotationBox.hasClass('hide')){
        $rotationBox.removeClass('hide');
        $('#payoffs .payoff-item:not(:first)').css({opacity:0});
        $('#payoffs .payoff-item:first').addClass('show').animate({
          opacity:0
        },'slow', function(){
            $('.payoff-bg-text').css({opacity:0});
            $('.popup .item').stop().css({opacity:0}).show();
            $rotationBox.stop(true,true).animate({top: 0},'slow', 'easeInOutBack',function(){$('.popup .item.show').stop().animate({opacity:1})});
        });
      }
    }


  });

  $window.bind('resize', function(){

    $('.bag-blank:first').height($window.height() + blankHeight);
    $('.bag-blank:last').height(blankHeight/2);

    $bags.width($window.width());
    $bags.height($window.height());

    $containerBox.css({left: -1 * index * $window.width()});
  });

  $bags.width($window.width());
  $bags.height($window.height());

});
```